# How to easily register an COM DLL (C#) on multiple computers?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, registry, installshield

A while a go I have created a COM DLL for my office application (Access). This application is being used on multiple computers. 
The DLL is being changed regularly and because of that I have to re-register the DLL (on all the computers) every time it has been updated.

The re-registering is now being done by copying the DLL files from the server to the local machines and executing the RegAsm.exe with a power-shell script (this mechanism is build in the start-up BATCH script of the application, which compares version numbers.

However, I find this process very unwieldy since I need to manually update my version text file each time I update the DLL.

Is there perhaps an easier way to just run/update my DLL with a single click so that it updates the DLL on all the computers in my network? I have full control over the company's server/computers. Perhaps with the InstallShield or something? (I haven't done much with it so my knowledge about the InstallShield is very limited).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about leaving the DLL on the server and having your office application automatically call the DllRegisterServer of your DLL when it starts up? I can't recommend how you'd do that in your particular application, but that works for us in our old Visual FoxPro apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, **single click** is what inspired devs at MS and the evolution of the **OneClick Deployment** Woohoo!!

What you need is a thorough go through of the article [Simplifying Deployment and Solving DLL Hell with the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973843.aspx)

Of course it does mention of COM also, so happy reading!

Also this [Choosing Between ClickOnce and Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will look into it.